# What is the default font of Quarto presentations?

Tags: r, quarto, reveal.js, bootswatch

I feel very stupid for asking; the titular question says it all.

I looked through what I think is the CSS from Bootswatch that provides the default theme, but didn't find any enlightenment there.

Comment: This link may provide some insight: https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/revealjs/themes.html or this one: https://quarto.org/docs/output-formats/html-themes.html

Answer (score 2):

The default CSS value for reveal.js presentations on Quarto is `Source Sans Pro, Helvetica, sans-serif`.

Comment: Che, gracias. Just so that I can figure out this kind of thing in the future, what did you look at to know this?

Comment: Al toke . I simply right-clicked on the text, inspect element and checked the font value.

Comment: look at the default value of font family [here](https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/revealjs/themes.html#sass-variables), and it is indeed `Source Sans Pro, Helvetica, sans-serif`